# Recommendations/Experiences for and with current Java EE/EJB3.0 Testing Frameworks (freebies)

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, ejb-3.0, integration-testing

I'm looking for your opinion on the technologies you have used successfully - or not so successfully - to automate your Java EE/EJB3 unit and integration testing.  I'll take advice on $$$ tools, but unfortunately the $$$ isn't in the budget at present.

We're currently embarking on the whole "let's standardize testing for our team" thing.  We've been using Groovy/JUnit for basic unit testing, but we need to add mock testing and integration testing, building this up into smoke tests that are run after each automated build to ensure that not only does the code compile, but works as expected. ;)

There's a myriad of things out there, like EJB3Unit, JMock, Mockito, Cactus, Arquillan... I could list all the things I've looked at as easily as you could too google "testing ejb3 Java EE".  I would appreciate YOUR two cents on what's worked well for you (or likewise, what to avoid).

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend Arquillian. Using it, you are able to test not only EJBs, but almost everything. It's also easy to use, to setup and it can be configured to execute your tests inside the actual running container.

Comment: Thank you!  My only concerns are around the "newness" of Arquillan (read: stability, robustness, support etc).

Comment: So, don't be concerned :-) Arquillan is a real project under jboss.org umbrella and some of the JBoss projects are using Arquillan for the test suite.